# .NET 4.0 Automating/Scripting certain actions

Tags: c#, .net, automation

I am a junior at university and quite new to the .NET framework.

Currently at my work in IT, there is a certain process in which an employee checks a MS office file, opens x applications, one after the other, and copies y files and waits on z conditions, one by one.

This process is quite long and tedious and very prone to human error. As such, I was wondering if .NET allows for some application to script this given sample procedure:

open a program,
input a string argument from an excel file,
get the output of the program,
paste the output of the program into another program,
get the output of the 2nd program,
open the output as a folder,
etc

The user should do as little work as possible (supplying some file paths and log-in credentials once and pressing some Start button).

If so, if someone could recommend a few good libraries/API to look at, it would be much appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

edit 1: System.Diagnostic.Process seems to not handle argument passing very well

Comment: .Net isn't really intended to be a scripting language for general-purpose automation.  You may want to look at other scripting languages like Delphi, VBScript, etc.  That being said, you may find it helpful to look at the [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class for starting multiple applications and waiting for completion.

Comment: You should look at Powershell. Powershell can leverage the entire .NET Framework and is meant for exactly the type of task you're describing.

Comment: For certain c# can do a lot of automation. But for some tasks other languages are preferable. That being said, there is a lot of staff that you can do with C#, you just have to be more verbose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Powershell, it is much better suited to what you are trying to do. Good place to start:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee221102

Answer (score 2):

I think you could do that more easily with [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/).

.NET/c# isn't really suited for that task as others have already pointed out.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion on AutoIt. The reason why I'm so insistent on .NET, is that my company allows it on its issued computers. Other applications they are very cautions about and there's a lot of red tape to bypass.

Comment: It might be possible to use the AutoIt libraries from within C#. See [this thread](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/39262-using-autoitx3-in-c/).